# Manage python string with special characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, encryption, special-characters

I need help to manage special characters in python. I'm working with a FPE library (pyffx) to encrypt data. Well, when my software encrypts the data there are no problems. When the software decrypts the data, it changes the format for example, by transforming a single `\` into `\\\\`. I tried to encode/decode with `utf-8` and also to maintain the raw value of the string. Here you can find an example of the encryption:

```
Encrypted data phase: uc?WL7+&u3*RAZuYPW1hc%/8sqX0?CBMlCCV-\mPC^RQ3&EsMRt|UIjs8KRLpzCbTI=3uBQcGWx6eXdVeV?nZmqCZtE/UAA\F7dbkuCTubyjng.%6AfhWh3H6V/b.ic7msw|lw-kiUuxCxCjPP%Uj.94h.*?ugB2j?TnujjL\2^aA2iYHGax?AQb7.VA76QTFcd7Ds2YL5OjI8Ue^Kmm9kC5t20M=mu8TDG4XK5xIifkUZMfWYYRa3£mbH/mGtAw\pN5nLOD2zEI/£82T7EKUa-v%*-l^GFS1-92t0N?EU&d7NEm&d|mbgl|fIKA-n|fEFV0OQ?OO^NmfDxiVsboMFho

Decription phase: b'uc?WL7+&u3*RAZuYPW1hc%/8sqX0?CBMlCCV-\\\\mPC^RQ3&EsMRt|UIjs8KRLpzCbTI=3uBQcGWx6eXdVeV?nZmqCZtE/UAA\\\\F7dbkuCTubyjng.%6AfhWh3H6V/b.ic7msw|lw-kiUuxCxCjPP%Uj.94h.*?ugB2j?TnujjL\\\\2^aA2iYHGax?AQb7.VA76QTFcd7Ds2YL5OjI8Ue^Kmm9kC5t20M=mu8TDG4XK5xIifkUZMfWYYRa3\\xa3mbH/mGtAw\\\\pN5nLOD2zEI/\\xa382T7EKUa-v%*-l^GFS1-92t0N?EU&d7NEm&d|mbgl|fIKA-n|fEFV0OQ?OO^NmfDxiVsboMFho'
```

In attachment you can find the example code:

```
def fpeencryption(data):
    e = pyffx.String(b'secret-key', alphabet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.|/%&£+-*=?^\\", length=len(data))
    print("Encription phase: " + str(data) + " size: " + str(len(data)))
    encrypted =  (e.encrypt(data))
    print("Encrypted data phase: " + str((encrypted)) + " size: " + str(len(data)))
    return (encrypted)

def fpedecryption(data):
    e = pyffx.String(b'secret-key', alphabet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.|/%&£+-*=?^\\", length=len(data))
    print("Decription phase: " + str((data)))
    decrypted =  e.decrypt(data.decode("utf-8"))
    print("Decr: " + str(decrypted))
    return decrypted
```

Data is a simple string with symbols/numbers/letter. Could you please help me? Thanks

**SOLUTION**

I solved the problem by changing the alphabet to:

```
alphabet=string.ascii_letters+string.digits+SPECIAL_CHARS
```

Comment: Do you have to use the back-slash in your alphabet ?

Comment: Also, how did you get that output ? how did you call the functions ? please share the driver code

Comment: This question would be helped greatly by a small addition of the input / output from the provided code. Please see if you can make a [mre].

Comment: Thank for your comments, I solved the problem and edited the response. Thanks you!

Comment: FYI, pyffx appears to use an early version of FPE from 2010.  To avoid known vulnerabilities, you may want to use a NIST approved FPE algorithm.  The approved ones are FF1 and FF3.  See Bellare, Hoang, and Tessaro. 'Message-recovery attacks on feistel-based format preserving encryption, ACM CCS 16, pages 444–455. ACM Press, 2016.'